# Completion block using showViewController:sender:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8

It exists some way to call a completion block when the presentation of view controller has finished using showViewController:sender: method.

Comment: What do you want to do in this completion handler? If you're passing data, you do that before you call `showViewController`. If you're trying to update `IBOutlet` controls in the destination, you shouldn't do that. And if you want to do something during the showing of the destination view controller, you do that in its `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, or `viewDidAppear` methods.

Comment: Also if you want to do custom `transitions` or `animations` you are better of implementing `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` or subclassing `UIStoryboardSegue`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I already knew these options, I asked because I'm using presentViewController and this method has completion block. And I want something to replace without to change all my project.